# Implementing jQuery UI toggle easing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm beginning to use the jQuery UI, and I'm trying to use an easing function other than the default ones available with the .toggle() effect in jQuery.

This is what I have now. How do I adjust this to use one of the easing functions from the UI, for example the 'explode' function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#signin').click(function(e) {
      $('#signinbox').toggle(300);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**per the docs:** http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/

**.toggle( effect [, options ] [, duration ] [, complete ] )**

```
 $('#signinbox').toggle('explode', 300);
```

Must include appropriate jqueryUI.js resources as this won't work with jQuery core `toggle()` method

Comment: Ah yes, I got it now. I went back to check my script sources and there was a `/` missing in the path. Thanks for the help.

Comment: when in doubt ...make the API your best friend

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$('#signin').click(function(e) {
    $('#signinbox').toggle('explode', 300);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sbvkW/)**